# Send message in FIFO order RabbitMQ and NserviceBus

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, microservices, nservicebus

We are building an application in .net using RabbitMQ and NserviceBus. We have to send messages to Hospitality Services. We want to be able to process messages in parallel. 
The issue we have is that **message order** at the receiving side is important. 
NServicebus does not support message ordering is there any workaround to achieve that.

Comment: Have you seen this blog post? https://particular.net/blog/you-dont-need-ordered-delivery

Comment: I'd also like to know what you think about the blogpost. If you don't agree, can you specify why you think you need ordered delivery?

Comment: HI @DennisvanderStelt , I had seen this blog post already. In some system ordering is not matter like Pizza shop example in blog but in some system it does. Like stock exchange where wrong order message can cause serious issues.